# Fade in and out using display property

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

```js
function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById("myDIV").style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById("second").style.display = "none";
}

function myFunction2() {
    document.getElementById("second").style.display ="block";
    document.getElementById("myDIV").style.display = "none";
}
```

```css
#myDIV {
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
    background-color: lightblue;
    display: none;
}
    
#second {
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
    background-color: lightblue;
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
<button onclick="myFunction2()">Try this now</button>
<div id="myDIV">
    This is my DIV element.
</div>
<div id="second">
    This is my DIV2 element.
</div>
```

The above code makes two divisions alternate in the same position. How can i manipulate the divisions in the way they appear and disappear. More specifically fade in(appear) fade out(disappear). Thanks

Comment: Google: CSS Animation. Google: CSS Opacity. Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

Use `jQuery` for event handling and `fade` animations:

HTML:

```
<button id="button1">Try it</button>
<button id="button2">Try this now</button>
```

Javascript:

```
$('#button1').on('click', function () {
    $('#second').fadeOut(2000, function () {
        $('#myDIV').fadeIn(2000);
    });
});


$('#button2').on('click', function () {
    $('#myDIV').fadeOut(2000, function () {
        $('#second').fadeIn(2000);
    });
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/rLvpqcLb/

Comment: @humble.rumble `jQuery` is tagged in question, have a look

Comment: @Tushar how can i make the fade in and fade out even slower?

Comment: @randy You can provide time duration in milliseconds as first param to `fade` functions. See updated answer

Comment: @Tushar just one final thing, now the fade in and fade out is between two elements, is the procedure applicable for several elements?

Comment: @randy Yes you can. Just add them inside `callback` of `fade` to make them animate one after other

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with css3 no jquery required, instead of display none use opacity 0

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <style>
        #myDIV {
            width: 500px;
            height: 500px;
            background-color: lightblue;
            opacity: 0;
            transition: all 2s linear;
        }

        #second {
            width: 500px;
            height: 500px;
            background-color: lightblue;
            display: none;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>

    <button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
    <button onclick="myFunction2()">Try this now</button>
    <div id="myDIV">
        This is my DIV element.
    </div>
    <div id="second">
        This is my DIV2 element.
    </div>

    <script>
    function myFunction() {
        document.getElementById("myDIV").style.opacity = "1";
        document.getElementById("second").style.display = "none";
    }
</script>
```